# How to get a final result from Observable.fromIterable()?

Tags: java, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I am getting a List<> of objects from network. I want to pass all the objects to a function and get a result when all the list is exhausted.

Here is what I am doing right now.

```
Observable.fromIterable(shortLinksList)
            .filter(shortLinkAlreadyExistsPredicate)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::insertLink);
```

How can I get notified when all the list is exhausted?

Comment: Maybe just implement `onComplete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to get notified you can use `onCompleted` on your `Subscriber`.
If you want a notification with all the items emitted previously, use [toList()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toList()) operator to collect all items emitted from `Observable` and get single notification with a list of Objects.

Comment: Implemented `onCompleted`, it is called only once, after all the list is completed processing. Thanks!